# How to stop receiving same SMS multiple times?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, sms, receiver

I have built the following Receiver class within a messaging app, which receives SMS messages anytime:

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
        SmsMessage[] smgs = null;
        String infoSender = "";
        String infoSMS = "";

        if (extras != null) {
            // Retrieve the sms message received
            Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
            smgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

            for (int i = 0; i < smgs.length; i++) {
                smgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                infoSender += smgs[i].getOriginatingAddress();
                infoSMS += smgs[i].getMessageBody().toString();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with it is that it sometime receives the same message multiple times, so I am suspecting that it's because the receiver is not unregistered and destroyed, so that it checks for incoming messages too often.

Hence, I've tried implementing this typical receiver class:

```
public class myReceiver extends MainActivity {
    BroadcastReceiver ReceiverOne = null;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED");
        ReceiverOne = new BroadcastReceiver() {
            @Override
            public void onReceive(Context arr0, Intent arr1) {
                processReceive(arr0, arr1);
            }
        };
        registerReceiver(ReceiverOne, filter);
    }

    protected void onDestroy(){
        super.onDestroy();
        unregisterReceiver(ReceiverOne);
    }
}
```

But now, ReceiverOne is never utilised, because there is no layout for this class and hence it's never called.  Is there any way to combine these two receivers?

Or better still, would anybody have any better suggestion as to why the first receiver is receiving some SMS messages multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

**Here is your Solution**  Get message and add it `StringBuilder` to make it single why you are getting `getOriginatingAddress` again and again its same for all sms parts.

```
public class Receiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED")) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            SmsMessage[] smgs = null;
            String infoSender = "";
            String infoSMS = "";

            if (extras != null) {
                // Retrieve the sms message received
                Object[] pdus = (Object[]) extras.get("pdus");
                smgs = new SmsMessage[pdus.length];

                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < smgs.length; i++) {

                    smgs[i] = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[i]);
                    sb.append(smgs[i].getMessageBody());

                }
                infoSender = smgs[0].getOriginatingAddress();
                infoSMS = sb.toString();
            }
         }
       }
    }
```

Comment: I'm afraid not - it's still receiving multiple times.

Comment: @BlackHedgehog check updated answer i have added a new check..`if (intent.getAction().equals("android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED"))`

Comment: @BlackHedgehog is your issue fixed?

Comment: No, I don't.  What do you think the problem is?

Comment: @BlackHedgehog your problem is almost fix you are missing something.